# How to track Notes and Attachment is viewed by user

Tags: notes

Basically i have a related list "Notes and Attachment" on account object, Now i want to track that how many times attachment is viewed or download by user in salesforce.

How i can achieve above task in salesforce.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: is this a compliance use case?  or, why do you want to do this?